# Why is the value of i not increasing in the python code below? What should I do to increase it?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, for-loop, python-requests

Why is the value of i not increasing in the python code below? What should I do to increase it?

```
i = 0
for z in analink2.iloc[i,[1]]:
    req = requests.get(z, headers = header)
    print(z)
    i += 1
```

```
analink2.head()
Out[268]: 
             section                                            weblink
0  bilgisayar-tablet  https://www.trendyol.com/bilgisayar-tablet-x-c...
1  bilgisayar-tablet  https://www.trendyol.com/bilgisayar-tablet-x-c...
2  bilgisayar-tablet  https://www.trendyol.com/bilgisayar-tablet-x-c...
3  bilgisayar-tablet  https://www.trendyol.com/bilgisayar-tablet-x-c...
4  bilgisayar-tablet  https://www.trendyol.com/bilgisayar-tablet-x-c...
```

I expect the value of i to increase and the index of z to increase with i as long as z is in the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over values in `weblink` column you can use next example:

```py
for url in analink2["weblink"]:
    print(url)
    req = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

---

If you want index value you can use for example `.iterrows()`:

```py
for idx, row in analink2.iterrows():
    print(idx, row['weblink'])
    req = requests.get(row['weblink'], headers=header)
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes very simple things get overlooked.